# Probability distribution of the maximum of random variables

Tags: probability

Given $N$ random iid variables, $X_1, \ldots, X_N$, with a uniform probability distribution on $[0, 1)$ what is the distribution of $\displaystyle \max_{i = 1 \ldots N}(X_i)$?

Comment: Shai Covo's post below is an easier way to the right answer. But I wanted to mention that this is a special case of an [order statistic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic).

Comment: Order statistics is better than what I need.

Comment: @user856; But the Order Statistics are not Independent.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hint: $\max \lbrace X_1,...,X_N \rbrace \leq x$ if and only if $X_i \leq x$ for all $i=1,...,N$.

Comment: But I guess after you order them , you destroy their independence, right? Once we know, e.g., the Min, that restricts other values.