# Does convergence in probability imply convergence in expected value?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value, probability-limit-theorems

Suppose that $Y_N \overset{p}{\to} Y$ as $N \rightarrow \infty$, i.e., $Y_N$ converges to $Y$ in probability. How do I prove that
$$ E(Y_N) \rightarrow E(Y) $$
as $N \rightarrow \infty$? This is easy when $Y_N \overset{a.s.}{\to} Y$ as one can apply dominated convergence theorem (since integration over a set of measure zero yields zero). My definition for the expected value is
$$ E(X)=\int_{\Omega} X dP, $$
where $\Omega$ is the space and $P$ probability measure.

Comment: To add to the answer below, note that convergence in probability implies convergence in distribution. But convergence in distribution does not imply convergence of expectation; see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153293/does-convergence-in-distribution-implies-convergence-of-expectation. However, when your sequence of random variables is *uniformly integrable*, then you do indeed get convergence in expected value.

Comment: This can work if the $Y_n$ process is bounded, say, $|Y_n|\leq b$ always for some finite constant $b$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does convergence in distribution implies convergence of expectation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153293/does-convergence-in-distribution-implies-convergence-of-expectation) (not an exact duplicate, but it the counterexample given there works here).

Answer (score 4):

This is not true. Even if $Y_n\to Y$ almost-surely we do not in general have $\mathbb EY_n\to\mathbb E Y$.

As a typical example of this, consider the random variables $Y_n$ defined by $$\mathbb P[Y_n=n]=1/n, \mathbb P[Y_n=0]=1-1/n.$$ Then clearly $Y_n\to 0$ but $$\mathbb EY_n = 1, \hspace{0.5cm} \text{ for all } n \in\mathbb N.$$

In fact, knowing $\textbf{when}$ we can deduce convergence of expected values is entirely the point of the convergence theorems (dominated convergence, monotone convergence...).

Comment: I see. What kind of additional assumptions on $Y_N$:s do I need for this to hold?

Comment: Well, any assumption that would allow you to apply some convergence theorem. For example (1) $0\leq Y_n\leq Y_{n+1}$ for all $n$ or (2) there exists an integrable $Z$ with $|Y_n|\leq Z$ or (3) $(Y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is uniformly integrable.