# Distribution of largest sample from normal distribution.

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

Given $n$ independent random variables $X_i$ with normal distribution, mean $\mu$, variance $\sigma^2$, what is the distribution of $\max\limits_{i=1}^n(X_i)$ ?

In particular I am interested in whether it would be Normal or close to Normal as well, and what the mean and variance would be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The random variable $Z = \max_{i=1}^n(X_i)$ is known as [order statistics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic), and is sometimes denoted as $X_{n:n}$.

The cumulative density function of $Z$ is easy to find:
$$
   F_Z(z) = \mathbb{P}\left(Z \leqslant z\right) = \mathbb{P}\left(\max_{i=1}^n(X_i) \leqslant z\right) = \mathbb{P}\left( X_1 \leqslant z, X_2 \leqslant z, \ldots, X_n \leqslant z\right) 
$$
using independence:
$$
   F_Z(z) = \left(F_X(z)\right)^n
$$
Thus the density function is 
$$
    f_Z(z) = n f_X(z) F_X^{n-1}(z)
$$
In particular, it follows that $Z$ is not normal.

Expected values of $Z$ are known  in closed form for $n=1,2,3,4,5$ (asking *Mathematica*):

```
In[31]:= Table[
 Mean[OrderDistribution[{NormalDistribution[m, s], n}, n]], {n, 1, 5}]

Out[31]= {m, m + s/Sqrt[Pi], m + (3 s)/(2 Sqrt[Pi]), 
 m + (6 s ArcTan[Sqrt[2]])/Pi^(3/2), 
 m - (5 s)/(2 Sqrt[Pi]) + (15 s ArcTan[Sqrt[2]])/Pi^(3/2)}
```

Large $n$ asymptotics is discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89030/expectation-of-the-maximum-of-gaussian-random-variables/89037#89037).