# How to derive the formula for the expected value for maximum of n normal random variables

Tags: probability, proof-explanation, normal-distribution

This is a follow-up question on this one: [Expected value for maximum of n normal random variable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/473229/expected-value-for-maximum-of-n-normal-random-variable)

@RobertIsrael states the following:

> Presumably the $X_i$ are independent.  If $\Phi$ is the standard normal cdf,
>   $$P(\max_i X_i < \mu + t \sigma) = \prod_i P(X_i < \mu + t \sigma) = \Phi(t)^n$$
>   so
>   $$ E[\max_i X_i] = \mu + \sigma \int_{-\infty}^\infty t \dfrac{d}{dt} \Phi(t)^n\ dt $$

I can see some of the ideas that lead to this formula (e.g. the multiplication because of independence) but I don't see all of the details. It would be very helpful if somebody could explain the derivation in detail... Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is basically using the definition of expected value and one simple substitution. The first equation can be rewritten as 
$$
\mathbb{P}(\max_i X_i < t) = \Phi\left(\frac{t - \mu}{\sigma}\right)^n.
$$
Then, by definition 
$$
\mathbb{E} \max_i X_i = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} t \cdot \frac{d}{dt} \Phi\left(\frac{t - \mu}{\sigma}\right)^n dt = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \sigma(t + \mu) \cdot \sigma \frac{d}{dt} \Phi(t)^n \frac{dt}{\sigma} = \mu + \sigma \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} t\cdot \frac{d}{dt} \Phi(t)^n dt,
$$
as desired.

So, in the first equation we used the substitution $t \to \sigma t + \mu$, in the second one we simplified the expression and used that integral of the density function over the whole domain is $1$.

Comment: Thank you, which definition are you using for the $d/dt$?

Comment: $\frac{d}{dt}$ is the derivative operator, so $\frac{d}{dt} \Phi(t)^n$ becomes the density function. is it clear now?

Comment: because the probability density function (which is used in the definition of expected value) is the derivative of cumulative distribution function

Comment: Yes, got it - Thank you!