# Hash Table: Probability that the longest chain has length k

Tags: probability

Say I have a hash table of size $m$, with collision handled by chaining. Assume the hash function hashes uniformly, so every key has probability of $\frac{1}{m}$ of being hashed to any slot in the table. I insert $n$ keys into the table. What is the probability that the longest chain in the table is size $k$?

My initial idea is like this:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{m}p_k^ip_{lk}^i$$

where $p^i_k$ is the probability of having $i$ slots with chain size $k$, and $p_{lk}^i$ is the probability of having $m-i$ slots with chain size less than $k$. I am able to get the probability of one slot having chain size $k$,but not sure how to derive the other probabilities from it. A pointer in the right direction is appreciated!

Comment: Exactly size $k$ or at least size $k$?

Comment: Exactly size $k$

Comment: The events aren't independent, so multiplying the probabilities doesn't look right.

Comment: I see... Then I am stuck... Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how to do it either, at least not yet.

Comment: There are a lot of "common sense" notions, that make it hard to extract the mathematical problem. What is for instance (mathematically) a "hash table" of some size, (a map?! from... to...?!) than "collision", than "chaining", what is a "hash function", a "key", a "slot" in the table, what is a "longest chain" after insertion... The idea is a formula, that it is hard to digest, it depends on new variables, defined by "slots". Some simple example may make things clear. Generally i do not downvote, but this is a case i would take it in consideration, since there is no point to start...

Comment: I took it to mean: Given $n$ iid variables $X_i$ taking values uniformly from $\{1,2, \ldots, m\}$, what is the probability that $\max_j( |\{i | X_i = j\}|    ) = k$?

Comment: Yes that is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

*Leaving the following answer even though it applies to a slightly different model than the one asked about.*

Consider the random variables $(A_{ij}\colon 1\leq i\leq m,\ 1\leq j\leq n)$ given by $A_{ij}=1$ if the $j^{th}$ inserted key hashes to slot $i$, and $A_{ij}=0$ otherwise. Then the variables $(A_{ij})$ are mutually independent and each distributed as a Bernoulli$(1/m)$ random variable. Let $S_i$ denote the length of the chain in slot $i$, or equivalently,
$$
S_i=\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}.
$$
Your question asks to find the distribution of $\max_{1\leq i\leq m}S_i$. Now we come to a branching off point: to some people, even rephrasing the problem in this way is already an answer, but I will outline some of the different paths one can choose to take from here.

Observe that $S_i$ is Binomial$(n,1/m)$ and the $S_i$ are independent. If an exact asymptotic is desired (for instance, assuming $m$ is $O(1)$ and $n$ tends to infinity) then one can use a Gaussian approximation to $S_i$ and follow similar approaches as in [Expectation of the maximum of gaussian random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89030/expectation-of-the-maximum-of-gaussian-random-variables) or [Bounds for the maximum of binomial random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/590880/bounds-for-the-maximum-of-binomial-random-variables) to get good bounds on the size of the maximum.

If weaker bounds suffice, you can follow the approach outlined here
[Maximum of $k$ binomial random variables?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2407870/maximum-of-k-binomial-random-variables)

If you need an exact formula, you can simply use the [probability mass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Probability_mass_function) to express things as a complicated sum.

Comment: But the $S_i$ are not independent. e.g., if $S_1 = n$ then we know $S_2 = \ldots = S_m = 0$.

Comment: The $A_{ij}$ are also not independent.  There can only be one $i$ with $A_{ij} = 1$ for each $j$, since each key hashes to only one slot.

Comment: @JairTaylor good catch, somehow I transformed the model in my mind when writing the answer. That being said, if one is interested in asymptotics when $m=o(n)$ then my model is a good approximation of the one in the problem statement, up to a simple rescaling.

Comment: Right, I think the asymptotics should be similar in that domain, although I'm not sure how to prove it.

Comment: It should be a relatively straightforward consequence of the strong law of large numbers at least for the regime $m=o(n)$, although I will hold off on working out the details until @William clarifies the question further.