# The law of large numbers - limits of $\max$ vs $\max$ of a limit.

Tags: probability, probability-limit-theorems, law-of-large-numbers

Assume that $X_{1,1}, \dots , X_{1,n}, X_{2,1},\dots, X_{2,n}, \dots ,X_{n,1}, \dots , X_{n,n}$ are i.i.d. random variables, and that $\mathbb EX_{i,j}$ exists and is finite. From the strong law of large numbers we have 
$$\max_i\left\{\lim_{n\to\infty}\left\{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}X_{i,j}\right\}\right\} \overset{a.s.}{=} \mathbb EX_{i,j} ,$$
because $\max_i$ is redundant. However, do we have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left\{\max_i\left\{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}X_{i,j}\right\}\right\}  \overset{a.s.}{=} \mathbb EX_{i,j} ? $$ 
I.e., can  we change the order of $\max$ and $\lim$ without affecting the result?

Comment: And your thoughts on this are?

Comment: I'm not sure why 3 have voted to close. Regarding my thoughts, I think the answer is yes, but I have no idea how to prove it. Perhaps it is just obvious, I'm not sure.

Comment: @David K I'm not following your logic. You see that the right hand side is just the left hand side with the limit and maximum interchanged, right?

Comment: I understand what the expectation operator is - if $X_{i,j}$ has density function $f_X(x)$, $\mathbb E [X_{i,j}] = \int xf_{X}(x)dx$.

Comment: I also understand that the strong law of large numbers states that $\lim_{n\to\infty}1/n(X_{i,1}+\cdots +X_{i,n}) \overset{a.s.}{=}\mathbb E [X_{i,j}]$. If we change the order of the $\lim$ and $\max$ operators in the LHS of my equation in the question, the law of large numbers can be applied immediately, which means that the $\max$ operator is redundant. Like I state in the question, my question can be rephrased as, can we change the order of $\lim$ and $\max$?

Comment: I did mean that, yes.

Comment: @David K On reanalysis of my question, I realise that I did not make it clear that the i.i.d. nature of the RVs applies over all $i$ also. This has been edited.

Comment: OK, now I get it (I think). You mean $\stackrel{a.s.}=$ where you write $=$. So I feel a little dense now. Good question. (Might be worth editing the $\stackrel{a.s.}=$ and a bit of your comment about the strong LOLN into the question itself, just to make it a bit more obvious.)

Comment: @David K, thanks for your input, I've made the changes.

Comment: If with $\underset{i}{\max}$ you mean to take the max for all $i\in\mathbb{N}$, I'd guess no. The probability of an $i\in\mathbb{N}$ existing such that $$\sum_{j\in\mathbb{N}}X_{i,j} = n\cdot(\mu+\epsilon)$$ for some $\epsilon>0$ is 1.

Comment: Sorry, I meant $j\in[n]$.

Comment: In general, you can't swap a maximum with a limit. For the equality to hold, you need an estimate of $\max_{i\leq n} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n X_{i,j} - \mathbb{E}[X_{1,1}]$. Then you need to see if this goes to $0$ with $n$. Assuming $X_{i,j}$ have finite variance, you can apply the central limit theorem and the second answer to this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89030/expectation-of-the-maximum-of-gaussian-random-variables, to estimate that the expression does converge to 0. Sorry this isn't a full answer, I don't have time to write it out.

Answer (score 0):

IF the all moments exist, then the answer is as follows.

Without loss of generality (and by doing and affine transformation $X\rightarrow aX+b$),  I assume
$$\mathbb{E}[X]=0; \hspace{3mm}\mathbb{E}[X^2]=1$$
Then, the moment generating function
$$g(s)\equiv \log\mathbb{E}[e^{sX}]$$
would satisfy
$$g(0)=0; \hspace{3mm}g^\prime(0)=0; \hspace{3mm}g^{\prime\prime}(0)=1$$
For each $i$, the variate $Y_i\equiv\frac1n\sum_jX_{ij}$ has
$$f(s)\equiv\log\mathbb{E}[e^{sY}]=ng(s/n)=\frac{s^2}{2n}+\mathcal{O}(\frac{1}{n^2})$$
Therefore the density for $Y$ is
$$p(y)=\sqrt{\frac{n}{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{ny^2}{2}}+\frac{e_n(y)}{n^2}$$
For some finite function $e_n(y)$. Now the question is: What is the asymptotic behavior of
$$Z\equiv\max_{i\in[n]}Y_i$$
Let's start by the cumulative distribution function
$$F_Z(z)=F_Y^n(z)=\Big(F_G(z\sqrt n)+\frac{e_n(z)}{n^2}\Big)^n$$
$$= F_G^n(z\sqrt n)+\frac{e_n(z)}{n}+\mathcal{O}(\frac{1}{n^2})$$
where $F_G$ is the cumulative distribution for a standard gaussian. This approximation holds for all real $z$ unless $|z|\ll \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$.

Next, let us try to calculate the moments for $Z$ using known results about the maximum of a set of independent gaussian variables.
$$\mathbb{E}[Z]=\int z F_Z^\prime(z)dz=\frac{C\log n}{\sqrt{n}}+\mathcal{O}(\frac{1}{n})$$
$$\mathbb{E}[Z^2]=\int z^2 F_Z^\prime(z)dz=\frac{C\log^2 n}{n}+\mathcal{O}(\frac{1}{n})$$
These mean
$$\boxed{Z\overset{a.s.}{=}0}$$
There are (small) gaps in my solution but the bounty is due, I had to hurry!