# concentration of maximum of gaussians

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

Let $X=(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$, where $X_i \sim N(0,1)$ are iid.

I'm looking for a result (and a proof outline) on the concentration of the max abs value of these Gaussians, $\|X\|_\infty$. That is, some result of the form $P(\bigl | \|X\|_\infty -\sqrt{2\log (2n)}\bigr |>t)<o(t)$, where $o(t)$ is any reasonable function that goes to $0$ as $t$ gets large.

I know these results: $E \|X\|_\infty \leq \sqrt{2 \log (2n)}$, $P(\|X\|_\infty \geq \sqrt{2 \log (2n)}+t)\leq 2\exp(-t^2 /2)$, which seems to be the "right tail" of the result I'm looking for.

Comment: Why is there a factor 2 to your $n$? Isn't the expected maximum $\sqrt{2\log n}\sigma$ for $X_i \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$?

Comment: @user32849: Yes, the expected maximum wouldn't have a factor of $2n$ but the absolute maximum would contain it since maximum of $|X_1,|\ldots,|X_n|$ is same as the maximum of $X_1,-X_1,\ldots,X_n,-X_n$.

Comment: Is that correct? See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1456567/expected-maximum-absolute-value-of-n-iid-standard-gaussians

Comment: @Jason Hi, I am wondering how do you obtain the result that $P(\Vert X\Vert_\infty \ge \sqrt{2log(2n)} + t) \le 2 \exp(-t^2/2)$?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So you just need to show that $P(\|X\|_\infty \leq \sqrt{2 \log (2n)}-\epsilon)$ is small. This is easy because 
$$
P\left(\|X\|_\infty \leq a_n\right) = P\left(|X_1|\leq a_n\right)^n = (2\Phi(a_n) - 1)^n\le \left(1-2\frac{a_n}{\sqrt{2\pi}(a_n^2 + 1)}e^{-a_n^2/2}\right)^n.
$$
Plugging $a_n = \sqrt{2\log (2n)-\delta}$,
$$
P\left(\|X\|_\infty \leq a_n\right) \le \left(1-\frac{\sqrt{2\log (2n)-\delta}}{\sqrt{2\pi}n(2\log (2n)-\delta + 1)}e^{\delta/2}\right)^n\\
\le \left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}n(\sqrt{2\log (2n)-\delta} + 1)}e^{\delta/2}\right)^n\\
\le \left(1-\frac{e^{\delta/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}n(\sqrt{2\log (2n)} + 1)}\right)^n\\
\le \exp\left\{-\frac{e^{\delta/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}(\sqrt{2\log (2n)}+ 1)}\right\},
$$
So you can take $\delta = K\log\log n$ with some $K$ large enough in order to make this small. You might be disappointed by the fact that this goes to infinity. This is not so bad as in fact the corresponding $\epsilon$ is of order
$$
\frac{c\log \log n}{\sqrt{\log n}}
$$
and does go to zero. If you want to have it fixed, you will get even some exponentially small estimates for probability.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Can you explain how you got the last ineq: $\left(1-\frac{\sqrt{2\log (2n)-\delta}}{\sqrt{2\pi}n(2\log (2n)-\delta + 1)}e^{\delta/2}\right)^n\\
\le \exp\left\{-\frac{e^{\delta/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}(\sqrt{2\log (2n)}+ 1)}\right\}$?

Comment: Thank you for your continued help, and sorry that I still have a question.  I get the intermediate step now, but it seems you use a result of the form $\lim_{n \to \infty}(1-x/n)^n=e^{-x}$, my only concern is that not all the terms of the seq are $\leq$ its limit (for instance, n=2, $\lim_{x \to \infty}(1-x/2)^2 =\infty$, but $\lim_{x \to \infty}e^{-x}=0$.  However, I'm fine w/ the last $\leq$ being $\approx$, for large n.  I'm just curious in general how to bound terms of the seq $(1-x/n)^n$, for x>0.

Comment: @Jason, $1+x\le e^x$ for all $x$, even for negative ones. And when both sides are positive (which is the case here), you can raise this to the power $n$.

Comment: but if you look at it as $(1+x)^n$ rather than $(1+x/n)^n$, then wouldn't you need an extra n in the denominator?  Again, thanks for your continued help.

Comment: So with your choice of x, I think the final bound should be $\leq \exp\left\{-\frac{e^{\delta/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}n(\sqrt{2\log (2n)}+ 1)}\right\}$

Comment: Ok, I see it.  Sorry it was something dumb  I overlooked.  Thx again for your help, I wish I can approve your answer twice.

Comment: @zhoraster Thanks for your answer, learnt from it. I wonder if the two sided estimate for the maximum of Gaussians can be generalized to subgaussians as well? So can we say that, $||X||_{\infty}$ concentrates near $\sqrt{ {2} log (2n)}?$

Also, could we have such an estimate for concentration of minimum of iid subgaussians $X_1 \dots X_n?$

Comment: @LearningMath, I'm not sure. Here in fact I speak of upper bounds rather than concentration. And I do need quite nice tail estimates. Maybe, for subgaussians this will work, but certainly not verbatim. It's better to ask this question separately.

Comment: @zhoraster Thanks for your comment - I'll surely ask this question separately and comment here when I do. By concentration, I indeed meant both upper and lower bounds or two sided bounds. It'd be nice if the proof goes through, with some modification, to subgaussians as well.

Comment: @zhoraster Hello again, I asked the corresponding question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3663396/concentration-or-two-sided-tail-bounds-around-expectations-of-maximum-and-mini, thank you for taking a look!

Answer (score 6):

I have the inequality you are looking for ! It gives concentration inequality reflecting the behaviour of extremes convergence (by this I mean, if $M_n$ is the maximum of your Gaussian variables, then $a_n(M_n-b_n)$ goes in distribution toward a Gumbel). Thus, the decay must be look like the Gumbel tails.

You can look at my article : http://perso.math.univ-toulouse.fr/ktanguy/files/2012/04/Article-3-brouillon.pdf

which give concentration inequality for extrema of stationary Gaussian processes wich look like

$\mathbb{P}( a_n(M_n-b_n)>t)\leq ce^{-ct}, t>0, n\geq 1$
with $a_n=\sqrt{\log n}$ and $b_n=\sqrt{\log n}+o(\sqrt{\log n})$ (the renomelazing constant of extremes theory)
same inequality for the other side also holds

Tell me if it helps. (The absolute value must not be an issue, you can also look to an article of Gideon Schechtmann about random Dvoretsky's theorem for $l_\infty$ balls (see [here](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-72053-9_15))).