# Concentration (or two sided tail bounds around expectations) of maximum and minimum of $n$ iid, subgaussian random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, random-matrices

Having no answer so far, I asked this on [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/360054/concentration-or-two-sided-tail-bounds-around-expectations-of-maximum-and-mini) now.

My question is motivated by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1460412/concentration-of-maximum-of-gaussians/1460650?noredirect=1#comment7502121_1460650) and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1460412/concentration-of-maximum-of-gaussians/1460650?noredirect=1#comment7502121_1460650), where the first was aimed for giving a one sided tail bound for maximum of subgaussians, and the second one was for two sided tail bounds for gaussians. I'm also motivated by questions like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/961780/prove-that-the-maximum-of-n-independent-standard-normal-random-variables-is-a?rq=1).

Let $\{X_1 \dots X_n\}$ be $n$ iid, subgaussian random variables so that $P[|X_i| \ge t] \le 2 exp (- \frac{ct^2}{ ||X_1||_{\psi_2}^2 }) \forall i, ||*||_{\psi_2}$ denoting the Orlicz norm. I'm looking for concentration inequalities for :

$$  X_{max} := max_{1 \le i \le n} X_i, \hspace{1mm}    X_{min} := min_{1 \le i \le n} X_i   $$

So to be more precise, I'm looking for tail bound functions $\alpha(t), \beta(t)$ of the form:

$$ P[  | X_{max} - \mathbb{E}X_{max} | \ge t ] \le  \alpha(t), P[  | X_{min} - \mathbb{E}X_{min} | \ge t ] \le  \beta(t)  $$

where the following are decreasing functions of $t$:

$$ 0 \le \alpha(t), \beta(t) \to 0, t \to \infty.$$