# Reference request: Distribution of a maximum Gaussian RV

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, order-statistics

when searching for the distribution of the extreme value of a large set of iid Gaussian RVs, I stumbled upon this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/89037/393397) by [Sasha](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/11069/sasha), which gave more accurate results than the approximation given in [Fisher & Tippett](https://hekyll.services.adelaide.edu.au/dspace/bitstream/2440/15198/1/63.pdf). 
There was no reference for the source of Sahsa's approximation, and it would be helpful if someone could direct me to some book or article that derives it.

Answer (score 0):

Sasha's answer cites

http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExtremeValueDistribution.html#6764486

The example there starting with the text "Construct an approximation for the distribution of maximum value in a normal sample of size $n$:" is the computation shown in her answer.

What more reference are you wanting?

Comment: The cited page doesn't give the derivation of the constants
$\mu_n = \Phi^{-1}\left(1-\frac{1}{n} \right) \qquad \qquad
   \sigma_n = \Phi^{-1}\left(1-\frac{1}{n} \cdot \mathrm{e}^{-1}\right)- \Phi^{-1}\left(1-\frac{1}{n} \right)$  it simply states the final result and show that it works.

Comment: These are ancient results.  See [Gumbel 1935](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/AIHP/AIHP_1935__5_2/AIHP_1935__5_2_115_0/AIHP_1935__5_2_115_0.pdf), eqn (14'), et seq.

Comment: Of course. How can one not be familiar with such elementary paper, published in a french statistics journal in 1935?

Comment: @avishayantman : Or, as one can find immediately from the linked Wikipedia page, *the* paper by Gumbel introducing th Gumbel distribution, the $\xi = 0$ case of the [generalized extreme value distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_extreme_value_distribution).  The referenced page also introduces the $\Phi^{-1}(1 - \frac{1}{n})$ and the GEVD page, Sasha's $F_{EV}$.