# Expectation of a partial derivative - Find upper bound of free energy (in Random Energy Model)

Tags: probability, statistics, expectation, statistical-mechanics

In the Random Energy Model, the Hamiltonian of a spin system $S_{N} =  \{ -1,+1 \} ^N$ is defined as $H_{N}(\sigma) = -\sqrt{N}X_{\sigma}$, where the $X_{\sigma}$ are i.i.d normally distributed. We are interested in the behaviour of the expectation of $\Phi$, which is defined as:
\begin{equation*}
\Phi_{\beta, N} = \frac{1}{N} ln Z_{\beta, N}
\end{equation*}
With Z the partition function:
\begin{equation*}
Z_{\beta, N} = \frac{1}{2^N} \sum\limits_{\sigma \in S_{N}}^{} e^{\beta \sqrt{N} X_{\sigma}} 
\end{equation*}

In this formulation of the model, the expectation of $\Phi$ has a very interesting property: it turns out that the law of large numbers holds up to a certain level of $\beta$ which we call the critical value $\beta_{c}$. Thus, up to this point it holds that $Z_{\beta, N} \sim E(Z_{\beta, N})$ and for $\beta > \beta_{c}$ a breakdown of the law of large numbers occurs. For a system of normally distributed $X_\sigma$ we have the following ground-state energy :
\begin{equation}
\lim_{N\to\infty} max_{\sigma \in S_{N}} \frac{X_{\sigma}}{\sqrt{N}} = \sqrt{2ln(2)},  a.s. 
\end{equation}
We want to follow the proof of Anton Bovier
    (Statistical Mechanics of Disordered Systems,
    Theorem 9.1.2) that the expectation of $\Phi$ now behaves in the following way: 
$   
\lim_{N\to\infty} E(\Phi_{\beta,N}) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{\beta^{2}}{2}, & \beta \leq \beta_{c} \\
\frac{\beta^{2}}{2} + (\beta - \beta_{c})\beta{c} ,&\beta \geq \beta_{c} \\
\end{cases}
$

From the previous we can derive that $E(\frac{d}{d\beta})\Phi \leq N^{-1/2} E(max_{\sigma \in S_{N}}X_{\sigma})$. 
Bovier now concludes the follwing two things:

1) $E(\frac{d}{d\beta})\Phi \leq N^{-1/2} E(max_{\sigma \in S_{N}}X_{\sigma}) \leq \beta \sqrt{2ln2} (1+C/N)$ with C a constant.

2) $E(\Phi) \leq \frac{\beta_{0}^2}{2} + (\beta - \beta_{0})\sqrt{2ln2}(1+C/N) =  ln{2} + (\beta - \sqrt{2ln2})\sqrt{2ln2}(1+C/N)$

I have no idea of how the $\beta$ and the constant $C$ pop up in the first equation, nor how the second expression follows from the first. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The second inequality in the claim (1) follows from the extreme value statistics of normal random variables (aside from the factor $\beta$, which I will discuss below). One source on this topic is Bovier's own set of lectures notes, which can be found [here](https://wt.iam.uni-bonn.de/fileadmin/WT/Inhalt/people/Anton_Bovier/lecture-notes/extreme.pdf). What's needed is nicely summarized in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/89037/27458) post, namely that the mean of the maximum of $n$ independent normal random variables is $m_n = M_N (1 + O((\log n)^{-1})$, where $M^2_n = \log(n^2 / 2 \pi \log(n^2/2\pi)) \le 2 \log n$.

Letting $n = |S_N| = 2^N$ and dividing by $\sqrt N$, this implies that
\begin{equation}
N^{-1/2} E \Big(\max_{\sigma\in S_N} X_\sigma\Big)
 =
N^{-1/2} m_{2^N}
 \le
\sqrt{2 \log 2}
\big(1 + C/N\big).
\end{equation}
As you can see $\beta$ is missing. I don't see where $\beta$ would come from as the $X_\sigma$ don't depend on $\beta$. Moreover, the presence of $\beta$ doesn't seem consistent with (2)

It is less clear to me how to get (2). By Jensen's inequality, $E \Phi_{\beta,N} \le \beta^2/2$. Thus, roughly speaking, we should have
(for any $\beta_0 \ge 0$)
\begin{equation}
E \Phi_{\beta,N}
 \approx
E \Phi_{\beta_0,N} + (\beta - \beta_0) \frac{d}{d\beta} E \Phi_{\beta,N}\big|_{\beta_0}
 \le
\frac{\beta_0^2}{2}  + (\beta - \beta_0) \sqrt{2 \log 2} (1 + C/N).
\end{equation}
(From this, you see why we wouldn't expect a $\beta$ in (1): it would lead to an extra factor of $\beta_0$ in the last term above.)
However, the $\approx$ is not an upper bound $\le$ since $\frac{d^2}{d\beta^2} E \Phi_{\beta,N} \ge 0$ for all $\beta \ge 0$. Nevertheless, this derivative should be negligible in the limit $N \to \infty$ (I have not done the computation so I'm not sure). In other words, we should be able to get a slightly weaker version of the inequality in (2), but this should suffice since we are taking the limit in the end.