# Demonstration for Expectation of the maximum of random variables

Tags: statistics

Hi fellow mathematicians,

I just a need a reference or a text book where I can find the demonstration for the expressions of $\mu_n$ and $\sigma_n$ in the attached figure.  This is from an answer by Sasha on [Expectation of the maximum of gaussian random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89030/expectation-of-the-maximum-of-gaussian-random-variables/89037#89037)

Thanks.

[expectation and sigma for max statistics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v70i8.png)

Comment: You might want to consider whether you can find what you want in Gumbel, E.J. (1954). [Statistical theory of extreme values and some practical applications](https://ntrl.ntis.gov/NTRL/dashboard/searchResults/titleDetail/PB175818.xhtml). Applied Mathematics Series. 33

Comment: Great you made may day.  The Gumbel derivation for $\sigma_n$ is even simpler.  Thanks a lot Henry!