# greatest of probabilities

Tags: probability, random-variables

My question is how to calculate the following formula without iteration:

$$ \max \{A,B,C,D\} \tag 1 $$

suppose $A,B,C,D$ are normal and independent:
I know (1) can be rewritten as

$$\max(\max(\max(A,B),C),D)$$

where

$$\max(A, B)= F(A)\cdot f(B) + F(B) \cdot f(A)$$

where $F$ is the CDF and $f$ is the PDF

if 
$$\max (A, B) = M_ab$$ 
then 
$$\max (A, B , C) = F(M_ab) \cdot f(C) + F(C) \cdot f(M_ab)$$ and so on.

Is there any other way for calculating maximum of $n$ random variables at once, instead of repetitively using pair-wise max?

(i.e $\max \{A, B, C, D\} = E$, where $E$ can be any type of distribution)

Answer (score 2):

If you have $n$ identically distributed and independent random variables each with

- cumulative distribution function $F(x)$
- and probability density function $f(x)$

then, by considering the probability that all $n$ of them are less than or equal to $x$ and then taking the derivative with respect to $x$, their maximum will be distributed with

- cumulative distribution function $(F(x))^n$
- and probability density function $n f(x) (F(x))^{n-1}$

Comment: what if they were not identical? they just multiplied to each other?

Comment: could you please show me some references or examples?

Comment: @nauok  For the CDF of independent non-identically distributed r.v.s you just multiply the individual CDFs.  The pdf looks rather like a generalisation of Yves Daoust's answer.  This is not difficult (it might be a book exercise): see for example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89030/expectation-of-the-maximum-of-gaussian-random-variables

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{\max(A, B)}{F(A)\cdot F(B)}= \frac{ f(A)}{F(A)} + \frac{ f(B)}{F(B)}$$

seems to generalize nicely.

Comment: thank you. so  max(a,b,c,d) will be [f(a)/F(A)+ f(b)/F(b) + f(c)/F(c) + f(d)/F(d)] * F(a) F(b) F(c) F(d) right?

Comment: @nauok: yes, right.