# maximum of i.i.d gaussian variable

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be a sequence of i.i.d Gaussian with mean $0$ and variance $\frac1n$, i.e. $X_i \sim\mathcal{N}(0,\frac{1}{n})$. What is the limit behavior of $Z=\max_i X_i$.

like $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{Z}{n^\alpha (\log n)^\beta}=C$ for some $\alpha $, $\beta$ and $C>0$

Comment: It is not clear why you have the variance of $\frac1n$, as it will lead to $Z \to 0$.  But an [earlier question and answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/89037/6460) deals with the maximum of standard Gaussians and you can easily translate it to your version