# Limit of expectation of maximum of standard normal distribution

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems, gaussian, extreme-value-theorem

I cannot find the way to show that

if $X_1,\dots,X_n$ are independent standard normal random variables, then

$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac {\mathbb{E} \max_{i=1,\dots,n}X_i}{\sqrt{2\log n}} = 1
$$

I could only show that $\mathbb{E} \max_{i=1,\dots,n}X_i \leq \sqrt{2 \log n}$

Comment: I think [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/89037) is helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the solved exercise 18.7 (pages 332 and 358) in [https://homes.cs.washington.edu/~karlin/GameTheoryBook.pdf](https://homes.cs.washington.edu/%7Ekarlin/GameTheoryBook.pdf)