# convergence of cumulative distribution function for the extreme value distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, normal-distribution, probability-limit-theorems

I am reading this interesting explanation (see second proof) of the

[Expectation of the maximum of gaussian random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89030/expectation-of-the-maximum-of-gaussian-random-variables/89037#89037)

And it is stated that $F_{EV}=exp(-exp(-(x-\mu_n)/\sigma_n))$.
$$
   \mu_n = \Phi^{-1}\left(1-\frac{1}{n} \right) \qquad \qquad
   \sigma_n = \Phi^{-1}\left(1-\frac{1}{n} \cdot \mathrm{e}^{-1}\right)- \Phi^{-1}\left(1-\frac{1}{n} \right)
$$
Here $\Phi^{-1}(q)$ denotes the inverse cdf of the standard normal distribution.

I would like to figure out where $F_{EV}$ converges to.

It seems that it converges to zero, but I am not sure how to show it.