# calculating $P(X_n=\max(X_1,X_2,\ldots, X_n))$

Tags: statistics

Suppose $X_1,X_2,\ldots X_{n-1}\sim U(0,1)$, $X_n\sim \exp(\frac{1}{2})$. Else, suppose $X_1,X_2\ldots, X_n$ are independent. How can I calculate $P(X_n=\max(X_1,X_2\ldots, X_n))$

Comment: Hint: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/313390/probability-density-of-the-maximum-of-samples-from-a-uniform-distribution

Comment: Since X1...Xn-1 are independent samples of the same underlying distribution, you can use order statistics to get the distribution of the maximum among these n-1 numbers. The following page gives you the exact formula, along with a nice explanation. Once you get the distribution for the maximum number, then you can compare that to the distribution for Xn. But recognize that both distributions are continuous -- did you mean to write "less than or equal to" or "greater than equal to" instead?

Answer (score 3):

The question's notation seems to encourage unnecessary confusion. It appears the OP is simply asking: `what is the probability that the Exponential drawing is the sample maximum?`

---

Let $(X_1, \dots, X_{n-1})$ denote a random sample of size $(n-1)$ drawn on a Uniform(o,1) parent, and let $Z = max(X_1, \dots, X_{n-1})$. It is well-known that the pdf of the sample maximum of size $n-1$ is:  $(n-1) z^{n-2}$ defined on (0,1). Then, if $Y \sim Exponential(\lambda)$ and independent, then the joint pdf of $(Z,Y)$, say $f(z,y)$, is:

[image]

**The problem**

The probability that $Y$ is the sample maximum is: $P(Y>Z)$, which can be automatically computed as:

[image]

where `Gamma[a,b]` denotes the incomplete Gamma function.

**Notes**

1. The `Prob` function used above is from the *mathStatica* package for *Mathematica*. As disclosure, I should add that I am one of the authors.
2. There are 2 common (but different) parameterisations of the Exponential distribution, and the OP does not specify which is being used, so to avoid any confusion, I have solved for general parameter $\lambda$.

Comment: have you drawn the figures on your own, or are they taken from some source? If so, which utility did you use? Thanks!

Comment: @nullgeppetto The figures are also plotted using _mathStatica/Mathematica_, using the actual functional forms of the densities.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X=X_n$ and $Y=\max\{X_k\mid1\leqslant k\leqslant n-1\}$, then $(X,Y)$ is independent and $P(X\geqslant x)=\mathrm e^{-x/2}$ for every nonnegative $x$ hence 
$$
P(X\gt Y)=E(\mathrm e^{-Y/2}).
$$
Furthermore $[Y\lt y]=\bigcap\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}[X_k\lt y]$ hence $P(Y\lt y)=y^{n-1}$ for every $y$ in $(0,1)$. Differentiating this yields the density of $Y$ and finally,
$$
P(X\geqslant Y)=\int_0^1\mathrm e^{-y/2}\,(n-1)y^{n-2}\,\mathrm dy=2^{n-1}(n-1)\gamma(n-1,1/2),
$$
where $\gamma(\ ,\ )$ is the [(lower) incomplete gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function#Definition).