# Algorithm L: Max of n samples drawn from uniform distribution U(0, 1)

Tags: uniform-distribution, sampling

I'm trying to understand algorithm L from reservoir sampling. One of the steps mentions that given n samples independently drawn from a uniform distribution U(0,1), we can simulate drawing n samples and getting the max with just drawing 1 sample can raising it to the power of 1/n.

That is max{random()_1, ...random()_n} = random()^(1/n)

Does anyone know how we get this result? Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define $z \sim D_z :=\max(r_1,\dots, r_n)$ for $r_i \sim_{\text{iid}} U(0,1)$ is
$P(z \le s) = s^n$, ([Proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/313390/probability-density-of-the-maximum-of-samples-from-a-uniform-distribution)), and reference its distribution by $D_z$.

Further, we can define $a \sim D_a:=U(0,1)^{1/n}$ and $t=a^{n}$, we have
$P(a \le s) = P(t\le s^{n}) =s^{n}$.

Therefore, $P(z \le s)=s^n=P(a \le s)$, implying $D_a=D_z$ as suggested.